# auth.log is empty (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, logging, syslogd

The **/var/log/auth.log** file in my Ubuntu 9.04 is empty. `syslogd` is running and **/etc/syslog.conf** content is as follows. Any help? Thanks.

```
#  /etc/syslog.conf     Configuration file for syslogd.
#
#                       For more information see syslog.conf(5)
#                       manpage.

#
# First some standard logfiles.  Log by facility.
#

auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warning                    -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

# Logging for INN news system
#
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some `catch-all' logfiles.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warning;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                         *

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#       *.=debug;*.=info;\
#       *.=notice;*.=warning    /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warning    |/dev/xconsole
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your permissions on /var/log/auth.log

Comment: what should they be?

Comment: `-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 210149 Dec  1 15:34 /var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 6):

When I had the same problem on Debian, I found I had to restart rsyslogd:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

(Your syslogd program may vary.)

The it started writing to /var/log/auth.log again.

Perhaps it had stopped logging after a disk full event, I'm not sure.

See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1059854/comments/9